# How to add a policy statement to a ecr repository

Tags: aws-cdk

How to add a policy statement to a ecr repository  although i know i can add a policy statement but in my case there are multiple statements so i am trying to attach a policy document for which i am getting compilation
**Here i am creating a policy document**

```
 let policy = new iam.PolicyDocument({
    statements: [
    new iam.PolicyStatement({
    sid: 'CrossAccountPermission',
    principals: principalArr,
    actions: [
    'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability',
    'ecr:BatchGetImage',
    'ecr:DescribeImages',
    'ecr:DescribeRepositories',
    'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer',
    'ecr:ListImages'
    ],
    }),
    
  //This is the second policy statement  
    new iam.PolicyStatement({
    sid:'LambdaECRImageCrossAccountRetrievalPolicy',
    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    principals: lambdaPrincipal,
    actions: [
    'ecr:BatchGetImage',
    'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'
    ]
    })
    ]
    });
    
**Here i am creating a repository for using the above policy statement**


    const ecrRepo = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryName(scope, 'repository');
    
    Now there is no method in ecrRepo to add policy document, although there is a method to add policy statement.
    
    Can someone please help me on how do i add multiple statement or policy document to a repo ??
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone looking for the answer, here is a snippet:

```
declare const repository: ecr.Repository;
repository.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
  actions: ['ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'],
  // resources: ['*'], // not currently allowed!
  principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
}));
```

More information is available in [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecr-readme.html#managing-the-resource-policy)